# No data_found setting variable to null

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, while-loop

The following code is setting the variable vBoleto to null when the select above return no rows. Can someone explain why please?
Sometimes vBoleto wont return rows from `sn_grupo_contestacao`, so I need to get the `id_boleto_origem` from the last vBoleto found in the `sn_boleto` table.

Here's the full code:

```
declare
  --20120807
  vContrato  sn_contrato.num_contrato%type := 18111110;
  vCid       sn_contrato.cid_contrato%type := '05509';
  vBoleto    sn_boleto.id_boleto%type := 82452735;
  vOrigem    sn_boleto.id_boleto%type;
  vGrupoCont sn_grupo_contestacao.id_grupo_contestacao%type;
  vParceiro  sn_grupo_contestacao.id_parceiro%type;
  vTot       number := 0;
  vStatus    number := 0;
 begin

    --- esboço ih - contestação com itens de outras cobrancas
    select id_grupo_contestacao, id_parceiro
      into vGrupoCont, vParceiro
      from sn_grupo_contestacao
     where id_boleto = vBoleto
       and fc_situacao_grupo = 'P'
       and num_contrato = vContrato
       and cid_contrato = vCid;

  exception
    when no_data_found then

      while true loop
        begin

          select id_boleto_origem
            into vOrigem
            from sn_boleto
           where id_boleto = vBoleto;

            vBoleto := vOrigem;

        exception
          when no_data_found then
            exit;
        end;
      end loop;

  end;
```

Comment: Your loop seems to be reinventing a hierarchical query. Presumably the top of the 'tree' has a null `id_boleto_origem`?

Comment: Hello. Yes it has a null boleto_origem, but when the exception is raised shouldnt the variable vBoleto keep the last value before the select into raising the no_data_found ?

Comment: no; you're doing `vBoleto := vOrigem;` after the select - presumably a row is found, but the id_boleto_origem (and therefore vOrigem) is null. So now your vBoleto is null too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable isn't being set to null when no data is found, it's being done on the previous iteration of the loop.

Lets say you have a simple structure:

```
create table sn_boleto (id_boleto number, id_boleto_origem number);
insert into sn_boleto values (1, null);
insert into sn_boleto values (2, 1);
insert into sn_boleto values (3, 1);
insert into sn_boleto values (82452735, 2);
```

Your first time around the loop:

```
select id_boleto_origem
from sn_boleto
where id_boleto = 82452735;

                       ID_BOLETO_ORIGEM
---------------------------------------
                                      2
```

So you set your vBoleto variable to 2 and repeat:

```
select id_boleto_origem
from sn_boleto
where id_boleto = 2;

                       ID_BOLETO_ORIGEM
---------------------------------------
                                      1
```

You set your vBoleto variable to 1 and repeat:

```
select id_boleto_origem
from sn_boleto
where id_boleto = 1;

                       ID_BOLETO_ORIGEM
---------------------------------------
                                 (null)
```

You have not got a `no_data_found` yet, so you still set your vBoleto variable to null; and repeat:

```
select id_boleto_origem
from sn_boleto
where id_boleto = null;

no rows selected
```

**Now** you get `no_data_found`, but it's too late, you've already set `vBoleto` to null.

You could avoid this by breaking out of the loop earlier, based on the value you did get rather than waiting for the exception:

```
      select id_boleto_origem
        into vOrigem
        from sn_boleto
       where id_boleto = vBoleto;

        if vOrigem is null then
          exit;
        end if;

        vBoleto := vOrigem;
```

---

Incidentally, your loop is reinventing [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm); you could replace that with:

```
...
  exception
    when no_data_found then

      select connect_by_root id_boleto
      into vBoleto
      from sn_boleto
      where id_boleto = vBoleto
      connect by prior id_boleto = id_boleto_origem
      start with id_boleto_origem is null;
  end;
```